# Solving $|x-2| + |x-5|=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could we solve $x$, in $|x+1|-|1-x|=2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98157/how-could-we-solve-x-in-x1-1-x-2)

How should I solve:
 $|x-2| + |x-5|=3$

Please suggest a  way that I could use in other problems of this genre too 
Any help to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,

Comment: The methods used [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98157/how-could-we-solve-x-in-x1-1-x-2) should work. Can you try reviewing those answers and possibly updating your question with any progress you make?

Comment: @TheChaz: my hint applies there as well :-)

Comment: [Robjohn argues](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17423082#17423082) that the two questions are the same. I think that there is a slight difference between $|x-1|-|x+1|=2$ and $|x-1|+|x+1|=2$, so I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, there are a couple of ways.

**Method 1. By cases.**

One is to consider cases: note that
$$\begin{align*}
|x-2|&=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x-2 & \text{if }x\geq 2\\
2-x &\text{if }x\lt 2
\end{array}\right.\\
|x-5|&=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x-5 &\text{if }x\geq 5\\
5-x &\text{if }x\lt 5
\end{array}\right.
\end{align*}$$
So, you consider what happens if $x\geq 5$, if $2\leq x\lt 5$, and if $x\lt 2$. In the first case, you have 
$$x-2+x-5 = 3$$
which is the same as $2x-7 = 3$, or $2x=10$, or $x=5$. Since this satisfies $x\geq 5$, that is one solution.

If $2\leq x \lt 5$, then you get $$x-2 + 5-x = 3$$
which is always true. So all numbers between $2$ and $5$ work (check and see this is true).

And if $x\lt 2$, you get
$$2-x + 5-x = 3$$
which is the same as $7-2x = 3$, or $2x=4$; that is, $x=2$. But $x=2$ does *not* satisfy $x\lt 2$, so there are no solutions here.

So the solution is that $x$ satisfies the equation if and only if $2\leq x\leq 5$.

**Method 2.** The absolute value is a measure of distance. $|x-2|$ is how far $x$ is from $2$, and $|x-5|$ is how far $x$ is from $5$. you are trying to find all numbers whose distance from $2$ plus their distance from $5$ equal $3$. Note that no number greater than $5$ can work, because then their distance to $2$ is already greater than $3$. No number smaller than $2$ can work because their distance to $5$ is already greater than $3$. And any number between $2$ and $5$, inclusively, *will* work, because if $2\leq x \leq 5$, then adding the distance from $x$ to $2$ and from $x$ to $5$ will necessarily add up to $3$. So the answer is that $x$ satisfies the equation if and only if $2\leq x \leq 5$.

Comment: explicit, but very explanatory (+1)

Comment: @Arturo Magidin:can i take the first case as x>5 like the third case?

Comment: @meg_1997: I don't understand your question. I divided the $x$ axis into $x\lt 2$, $2\leq x\lt 5$, and $5\leq x$. If you change the third case to $5\lt x$, then you need to change the second case to $2\leq x\leq 5$ to include all numbers.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin yes i got your point.And also it seems that its extremely necessary to  consider the right cases

Comment: @Arturo Magidin:What does it means when it is said that solve the above question using geometric interpretation of |x-a|

Comment: @meg_1997: It means you can think of it geometrically, instead of algebraically. $|x-a|$ is the distance from $x$ to $a$, so equations involving $|x-a|$ can be interpreted as statements about the distance from a point $x$ to $a$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin:In accordance with the above question can you give me hints to solve it geometrically then i will try it that way

Comment: algebraically i have  completely got it..thanks a lot

Comment: @meg_1997: I don't understand. I wrote down *exactly* how you would argue geometrically in that paragraph. What do you mean, "give you hints"? I gave you the *full explanation* of how geometric considerations give you the answer.

Comment: ohh ok well i thought something else about geometric considerations

Comment: but now i got even that!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

One characterization of "$x$ is between $a$ and $b$" is
$$
|x-a|+|x-b|=|a-b|
$$