# Solving $\sqrt{x^2 +2x + 1}-\sqrt{x^2-4x+4}=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is: Solve  $\sqrt{x^2 +2x + 1}-\sqrt{x^2-4x+4}=3$

I deduced that:$LHS= x+1-(x-2)$

I am unable to solve this equation.  I would like to get some hints to solve it.

Comment: By "whole root" do you mean square root, as in $\sqrt{x^2+2x+1}-\sqrt{x^2-4x+4}=3$?

Comment: Yes i meant the square root

Comment: like the one posted by André Nicolas

Comment: Abstract duplicate of [this recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98157) and [this one.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153818)

Comment: Please refer to : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167087/what-is-the-algorithm-for-solving-an-equation-like-this-one

Answer (score 8):

$$\sqrt {x^2 +2x + 1}-\sqrt { x^2-4x+4}= \sqrt{(x+1)^2} - \sqrt{(x-2)^2}=|x+1|-|x-2|$$

You have to consider three cases:

- $x \geq 2$
- $-1<x<2$
- $x \leq -1$

Comment: I didn't write the full solution as you asked for hints to solve it on your own.

Comment: Hey but there is a whole root sign

Comment: Oops, sorry. I'm not used to English-mathematics-nolatex notation!

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt {x^2 +2x + 1}-\sqrt { x^2-4x+4}= \sqrt{(x+1)^2} - \sqrt{(x-2)^2}=|x+1|-|x-2|=3$

$|x+1|-|x-2|=3$

1) $x\in(-\infty, -1)$$\Rightarrow$$|x+1|=-(x+1)=-x-1$, $|x-2|=-(x-2)=2-x$.

$|x+1|-|x-2|=3$$\Rightarrow$ $-x-1-2+x=3$$\Rightarrow$$-3=3$, this is a contradiction.

In this interval equation has no solution.

2) $x\in[-1, 2)$$\Rightarrow$ $|x+1|=x+1$, $|x-2|=-(x-2)=2-x$.

$|x+1|-|x-2|=3$$\Rightarrow$ $ x+1-2+x=3$ $\Rightarrow$$2x=4$$\Rightarrow$$x=2$.

$2\notin [-1, 2)$. Also in this interval equation has no solution.

3)  $x\in(2, \infty)$$\Rightarrow$ $|x+1|=x+1$, $|x-2|=x-2$.

$|x+1|-|x-2|=3$$\Rightarrow$ $ x+1-x+2=3$ $\Rightarrow$$3=3$.

On this interval equation has infinity solutions.

Comment: More precisely, the last interval **is** the solution set. It would still have "infinity solutions" if the solution set were, say, $(2,3)$, or the set of integers greater than $2$.

Comment: Nitpick: The number $2$ is not contained in any of your intervals now.