# What is the algorithm for solving an equation like this one?

Tags: problem-solving, learning

The solutions of the equation : $\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{x-2 \sqrt{x-1}} = 2$ are:

- A) $x=1$;
- B) $x=2$;
- C) $x\in [1,2]$;
- D) $x\in \begin{bmatrix}
      \frac{3}{2},2
      \end{bmatrix}$;
- E) $x=\frac{3}{2}$;

Comment: It should hardly be worth mentioning (though I'm often surprised to find that it isn't a universally-applied strategy) that (A), (B), and (E) can be quickly determined by simple substitution.

Comment: Define "like this one".

Comment: Check the ones that are easy to check by substitution.  Once you verify that $x=1$ and $x=2$ both work, answer (C) is the only possibility.

Comment: @RickDecker: Well, I don't know about *simple* substitution in the $x=\frac 3 2$ case....

Comment: @Cameron Well, for sufficiently complicated values of "simple" it is, but I'll concede your point. I still stand by my parenthetical remark, though

Comment: @Rick: I definitely agree with the parenthetical remark!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have some answer possibilities you can just check if they solve your equation. Denoting your right hand side by
\[ f(x) = \sqrt{x + 2\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{x - 2\sqrt{x-1}}, \]
we have

- $f(1) = 2$,
- $f(2) = 2$,
- $f(\frac 32) = 2$,

so C) is the only possibility.

If you don't have choices given, you could try to rewrite $f$, noting that the maximal domain of definition of $f$ is $[1,2]$. We have
\begin{align*}
  f(x)^2 &= x + 2\sqrt{x-1} + 2\sqrt{(x+2\sqrt{x-1})(x-2\sqrt{x-1})} + x - 2\sqrt{x-1}\\
         &= 2x + 2\sqrt{x^2 - 4(x-1)}\\
         &= 2x + 2\sqrt{x^2 - 4x + 4}\\
         &= 2x + 2\sqrt{(x-2)^2}\\
         &= 2x + 2\left|x-2\right|\\
         &= 2x + 2(2-x)\\
         &= 4
\end{align*}
As $f$ is non-negative, this gives $f(x) = 2$ for all $x \in [1,2]$ (that is, where $f$ is defined).

Comment: "noting that the maximal domain of definition of $f$ is $[1,2]$." Isn't $D_f=[1,+\infty)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\sqrt{x\pm 2\sqrt{x-1}}=\sqrt{(\sqrt{x-1}\pm 1)^2}=|\sqrt{x-1}\pm 1|
$$
So
$$
f(x)=|\sqrt{x-1}-1|+|\sqrt{x-1}+1|=|\sqrt{x-1}-1|+\sqrt{x-1}+1
$$
After considering cases $x>2$ and $1\leq x\leq 2$ you get
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2\sqrt{x-1}&\quad\text{ if }\quad x>2\\
2&\quad\text{ if }\quad 1\leq x\leq 2
\end{cases}
$$
From there it is easy to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient one (but not always convergent) is Newton-Raphson's method:
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n-f(x_n)/f'(x_n)
$$
or it's numeric equivalent (small steps for incrementing)

For the initial guess you can use an Exhaustive Search (e.g start from -10 to +10) and for halting a "difference checking while loop" would do good.

You can also use Bisection method which has a convergence guaranty.

Comment: You have missed the point entirely!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x-1=y^2$,

then the given equation becomes $\sqrt{y^2+1+2y}+\sqrt{y^2+1-2y}=2$

Now. $\sqrt{y^2+1+2y}$=(y+1) if (y+1)>0 i.e., y≥-1, else -(y+1)

and  $\sqrt{y^2+1-2y}$=(y-1) if y>1, else -(y-1)

Then, three cases arise, y< -1,  -1≤y≤1  and y>1.

If y < -1,   the given equation becomes -(y+1)-(y-1)=2 => y=-1 which is not possible as y < -1.

If -1≤y≤1, y+1 -(y-1)=2 which becomes identity=> one set of solution is -1≤y≤1.

If y>1 y+1+(y-1)=2 => y=1  which is again impossible as y>1.

If -1≤y≤1, 0≤$y^2$≤1 => 1≤$y^2+1$≤2 => 1≤x≤2

Answer (score 0):

If $ x < 1 $, then
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
f(x) & = & \sqrt{x + 2\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{x - 2\sqrt{x-1}} \\
& = & \sqrt{x + 2I \sqrt{1 - x}} + \sqrt{x - 2I \sqrt{1 - x}} \\
& = & \sqrt{\left( 1 + I \sqrt{1 - x} \right)^2} + \sqrt{\left( 1 - I \sqrt{1 - x} \right)^2} \\
& = & \pm \left( 1 + I \sqrt{1 - x} \right) + \pm \left( 1 - I \sqrt{1 - x} \right) \\
& = & \left\{ \pm 2, \ \pm I \sqrt{1 - x} \right\} \ni 2
\end{array}
$$