# Solving $|x+2| = 4 + |x-7|$

Tags: absolute-value

How would one solve the following equation over $\mathbb R$?

$$|x+2| = 4 + |x-7|$$

Comment: Can you tell us what you have done to try solving this?

Comment: $|x|$ means absolute value, which means non-negative number, if input number like $-3$, it will become $|-3| = 3$, but remain unchanged for positive number

Comment: You can have a look at some similar posts from the past. For example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98157/how-could-we-solve-x-in-x1-1-x-2

Answer (score 2):

We can write it as $|x+2|-|x-7| = 4$

Using $$|x+2|-|x-7| = \left\{\begin{matrix}
 -(x+2)+(x-7)&\;, x\leq -2 \\\\
x+2+x-7 & \;, -2<x \leq 7\\\\
 x+2-(x-7)& , x>7
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$\bullet\; $ If $x\leq -2\;,$ Then equation convert into $-x-2+x-7=4\Rightarrow -9=4\;\; \text{(False)}$

$\bullet\; $ If $-2<x \leq 7\;,$ Then equation convert into $x+2+x-7=4\Rightarrow \displaystyle x=\frac{9}{2}\;\; \text{(True)}$

$\bullet\; $ If $x\geq 7\;,$ Then equation convert into $x+2-x+7=4\Rightarrow 9=4\;\; \text{(False)}$

So we get only one solution which is $\displaystyle x = \frac{9}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Break it where $x\leq -2$ and $-2\leq x\leq7$ and $x\geq 7$
forexample for first one $$|x+2| - 4 - |x-7|=-(x+2) - 4 -(- (x-7))=0‎‎‎‎‎‎\Rightarrow‎ -2-4-7=0 $$ isnot acceptable. for second interval 
$$|x+2| - 4 - |x-7|=(x+2) - 4 -(- (x-7))=0‎‎‎‎‎‎\Rightarrow‎ 2x+2-4-7=0 ‎‎‎‎‎‎\Rightarrow‎ 2x-9=0 ‎‎‎‎‎‎\Rightarrow‎ x=\frac{9}{2}$$ which is acceptable.

for third interval
$$|x+2| - 4 - |x-7|=(x+2) - 4 - (x-7)=0 \Rightarrow‎ 2-4+v=0$$ whichisnot acceptable. thus answer is only $x=\frac{9}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$|x+2| = 4+ |x-7|$$
Statement 1: if $|x+2| > 0$, then $|x+2| = x+2$

Statement 2: if $|x+2| < 0$, then $|x+2| = -x-2$

Statement 3: if $|x-7| > 0$, then $|x-7| = x-7$

Statement 4: if $|x-7| < 0$, then $|x-7| = -x+7$

if Statement 1 and Statement 3, we will have:
$$x+2 = 4 + x - 7$$
$$2 = 4 - 7$$

thus, no answer, try Statement 1 and Statement 4

$$x+2 = 4 -x+7$$
$$2x=9, x= \frac 92$$

First answer, $x= \frac 92$ or $x=4.5$

Do the same thing for Statement 2 and Statement 3, Statement 2 and Statement 4. You get $x=\frac 12$ or $x=0.5$ Statement 2 and Statement 4, but no answer for Statement 2 and Statement 3

Now check your answer, $|4.5+2| = 4 + |4.5-7|$, $6.5 = 4 + 2.5$

$|0.5+2| = 4 + |0.5+7|$, $2.5 \ne 4+7.5$

thus, the answer is 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$ |x+2|-|x-7|=4 $$[image]

So the only solution is $ x=\frac{9}{2}.$
This method is useful when you will solve inequalities with absolute value.

[image]