# Solving $3|2-x| + |2x-4| = 8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I'm not sure how to solve $3|2-x| + |2x-4| = 8$. I don't exactly need an answer, the method is what I'm interested in. I've done equations with one absolute value element. >_<

Comment: Consider the cases $x <\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2 \leq x \leq 2, x>2$ separately.

Comment: Well, the obvious way is to consider when the expressions within the parentheses change their signs. So break up the equation at $2-x = 0$ and $2x-4= 0$. This time, it turns out that they're the same point.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: In this case, noticing $|2x-4|=2|x-2|$ simplifies things substantially. In connection with solving equations with absolute values, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98157/how-could-we-solve-x-in-x1-1-x-2) and [other posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/98157) might be useful.

Comment: BTW I am not really sure why this is tagged (inequality) , when the question is about solving an equation.

Comment: $|2-x|$ and $|4-2x|$ both equal $0$ at $x = 2.$  You have two cases to consider $x \le 2$ and $x > 2$

Answer (score 3):

$ 3|2-x| + |2x-4| = 8 \iff 5|x-2|=8 \iff 5(x-2)= \pm 8.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Almost, so this suggests |2-x| = |x-2| ?

Comment: $|a-b| = |b-a|$.  Always.

Comment: Because $b-a = -(a -b)$ and $|M| = |-M|$.  So $|a-b| = |-(b-a)| = |b-a|$.  Always.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

As for real $a,|a|=|-a|$

$|2(x-2)|=2|x-2|=2|2-x|$

Finally if $|y|=b\ge0,y=\pm b$ for real $y$

If $y$ is complex, we can set $y=p+iq$ where $p,q$ are real

If $|y|=b,\sqrt{p^2+q^2}=b$

Comment: Seriously, could the downvoter explain their action? That would help the non-specialist understand what's the problem in an answer from a high-rep user (my guess is $|a|=||-a$ ?)

Comment: @RingØ, Sorry for the obvious typo.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but explaining a dv would help, my $0.02c$...

Comment: @RingØ, Wish somebody take the pain to share the mistake

Comment: Well, I'd never down-vote this but I'd pretty sure its more abstract and advanced than the OP is prepared for.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it *THIS* case,  $|2x-4| = 2\cdot |x-2|= 2\cdot |2-x|$ so $3|2-x| + |2x-4| = 3|2-x|+2|2-x| = 5|2-x| =8$ so 
$|2-x| =|x-2|= \frac 85$ and so $x-2 =\pm \frac 85$ and $x = \frac 85 + 2=\frac {18}5=3\frac 35$ or $x = 2-\frac 85 = \frac 25$.

But in general do cases.

Do cases:

$2-x \ge 0$ if $x \le 2$ and $2-x < 0$ if $x > 2$.

And $2x-4 \ge 0$ if $x \ge 2$ and $2x-4 < 0$ if $x < 2$.

So do cases:

Case 1:  $x < 2$ and $2-x >0$ so $|2-x| = 2-x$ and $2x-4< 0$ so $|2x-4| = 4-2x$ and we have

$3|2-x| + |4-2x| = 8$

$3(2-x) + (4-2x) = 8$

$10 - 5x = 8$

$5x =2$ and $x =\frac 25$.

Case 2:  $x = 2$ and $2-x=0$ and $2x-4=0$ and so we have

$3|2-x| + |4-2x| = 8$

$3*0 + 0 = 8$

$0 = 8$ which is impossible.

Case 3: $x > 2$ and $2-x < 0$ so $|2-x| = x-2$ and $2x -4 > 0$ so $|2x-4| = 2x -4$

So

$3|2-x| + |2x-4| = 8$

$3(x-2) + (2x-4) = 8$

$5x - 10 = 8$

$x = \frac {18}5 = 3\frac 35$.